# Build 3D array from subarrays generated by meshgrid and introduce a 3th dimension

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am new to Python and I would like to build a full 3D array with dimensions = 1e3 x 1e3 x 16.

For this, I tried to do :

```
dimBlocks = 4
numElBlock = 1000
numPoints = 1000

arrayCrossX = np.linspace(kMIN, kMAX, numPoints, endpoint=True)
arrayCrossY = np.linspace(-1, 1, numPoints, endpoint=True)

coordCrossX, coordCrossY = np.meshgrid(arrayCrossX, arrayCrossY)
arrayFullCross = np.array(coordCrossX.size, coordCrossY.sizes, dimBlocks**2)
```

But it doesn't work, I get the following error :

`arrayFullCross = np.array(arrayCrossX.size, arrayCrossY.size, dimBlocks**2) ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted`

What might be wrong with building this full 3D array from subarrays `coordCrossX`, `coordCrossY` and with a third dimension equal to `dimBlocks**2 = 16`?

Comment: Apart from that: Using for example 64-bit numbers, your array would have a size of over 100TB

Comment: are you sure ? 1000x1000x16x8 = 128 Mo

Comment: excuse me, I don't how to handle with meshgrid

Comment: I would like to have meshgrid with 2D array of 1000x1000 and that, for 16 blocks

Comment: Oh you edited it; it said 1e6 x 1e6 x 16 before. With 1e3 x 1e3 x 16 it's perfectly doable

Comment: yes, this was an error, sorry. As I said in my last comment, I would like to have a 2D array (discretized along x and y) of dimension 1000x1000, and have 16 arrays2D like this, what do you advice me ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, what you want tbh. From what I understand, you want 16 2D arrays stacked to a 3D array? Where do these 2D arrays come from? I only see 2: `coordCrossX`and `coordCrossY`

Comment: @user8408080 yes, this is what I would like to get. These 2D arrays come from the meshgrid but unfortunately, `coordCrossX` and `coordCrossY` have each 1e6 elements, it's too big : how to get a 2D array with only 1e6 while having a third dimension. I would like to set the same values of 2D arrays for each of the 16 blocks. The issue here is that I don't know to merge the 2 meshgrid (`coordCrossX` and `coordCrossY`) to have only only one 2D array. Do you understand my problem ? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You get two arrays (`coordCrossX` and `coordCrossY`), which seem to have the shape 1e3 x 1e3. So with these two, we could make a 1e3 x 1e3 x 2 array. Where do the other 14 arrays come from?

Comment: @user8408080. You don't have to be sorry, I make confusions with meshgrid. Actually, I want to store on (i,j) element (a value, not an index) of a 2D array discretized along (x,y) axis. Up to now, it's simple. The position of this element is located by (i,j) indices but in fact, the index `i`and `j`represent coordinates values on the 2D domain. So, I would like to access to the value of element (at `(i,j)` indice corresponding to a physical value `xPhysical` which is equal to `crossCoordX[i] = xPhysical` and `crossCoordY[j] = yPhysical`.

Comment: @user8408080 Then, I will put at this point the value (it could be the temperature, the speed etc... ) that I will use later in my code like. Finally, I want have a 3D array with which I could do : `arrayFullCross[i][j][0] = temperature[i][j]` . The third dimension is like to have 16 x 2D array maps of temperature. You can understand better the issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188162/discussion-between-user8408080-and-youpilat13).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arrayFullCross = np.array(arrayCrossX.size, arrayCrossY.size, dimBlocks**2)
ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted
```

The signature for `np.array`:

```
array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0)
```

The proper way to use `np.array`:

```
In [658]: np.array([1,2,3], float)   # 2 nonkeyword arguments
Out[658]: array([1., 2., 3.])
```

That is, the object you want to make the array from, followed by optional `dtype`.  Anything else has to a parameter like `copy`.

You provide 3 positional arguments. Since they are all sizes, you need to use something like `np.zeros`:

```
np.zeros( (arrayCrossX.size, arrayCrossY.size, dimBlocks**2) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. **So what could be the utility of using `meshgrid` in the declaration of this 3D array ?** I am talking about the 2D array (refering yo the two first index of 3D array), i.e the 2D array which gives the physical 2D position with for example `[x,y] = [arrayCrossX[i], arrayCrossY[j]]`